# Подскажите как объявить несколько пространств имен в одном проекте

Tags: c#, namespace

Не знаю как это сделать,т.к недавно только начал разбирать что да как в Visual Studio,ну что то вроде "нарыл", получается на один проект в решение есть одно корневое пространство имен(то что одноименное с именем проекта по умолчанию) и надо добавить к проекту папки и в них уже закидывать файлы с классами чтоли,тогда выходит одно корневое пространство имен и n-количество под-пространств,к примеру как System и System.IO?
А вот если есть необходимость,к примеру к 2ум корневым пространствам имен,нужно делать аналогично?

Comment: вы бы руками сами попробовали что то сделать, сразу бы стало гораздо понятней. А так вы просто тратите впустую своё время и наше.

Comment: @tym32167 пол-интернета перерыл уже,пробую вот,получается все равно под-пространства всякие, корневого неймспейса (MyProject одноименный с названием проекта).Могу только ,создать папку в проекте(MyFolder),добавить туда класс получится пространство имен MyProject.MyFolder,удалить имя корневого пространства и оставить только имя MyFolder.Это и есть корневое пространство чтоли?Просто при добавлении новых классов в папку все равно получается у этих добавленных классов неймспейс MyProject.MyFolder и приходится все переписывать вручную.Можно ли без переписи как нибудь обойтись?Заранее благодарен.

Comment: @tym32167 точнее не одноименный с проектом неймспейс, а определенный по умолчанию(имя неймспейса)